# how do I set up my window function properly? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I want to get the first entry (datum, crop_type) where a specific crop is cultivated. the list I want to extract that information from is already ordered by year and month, however I have no idea, how to set up the window function properly. I think the easiest way would be to go back from each respective harvest (where yield_fm is != 0) and crop type is != 999999, but as I said, no idea how to do this.

snippet from my table:

```
"datum","crop_type","yield_fm"
1996-01-01,3,0
1996-02-01,3,0
1996-03-01,3,0
1996-04-01,3,0
1996-05-01,3,0
1996-06-01,3,0
1996-07-01,3,0
1996-08-01,3,9.5
1996-09-01,999999,0
1996-10-01,999999,0
1996-11-01,999999,0
1996-12-01,999999,0
1997-01-01,999999,0
1997-02-01,999999,0
1997-03-01,999999,0
1997-04-01,16,0
1997-05-01,16,0
1997-06-01,16,0
1997-07-01,16,0
1997-08-01,16,0
1997-09-01,16,53.7
1997-10-01,999999,0
1997-11-01,3,0
1997-12-01,3,0
1998-01-01,3,0
1998-02-01,3,0
1998-03-01,3,0
1998-04-01,3,0
1998-05-01,3,0
1998-06-01,3,0
1998-07-01,3,0
1998-08-01,3,8
1998-09-01,999999,0
1998-10-01,3,0
1998-11-01,3,0
1998-12-01,3,0
1999-01-01,3,0
1999-02-01,3,0
1999-03-01,3,0
1999-04-01,3,0
1999-05-01,3,0
1999-06-01,3,0
1999-07-01,3,0
1999-08-01,3,8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless columns specify the ordering.

If you want the first row per crop type, then in Postgres, I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (crop_type) t.*
from t
order by crop_type, datum;
```

`distinct on` is Postgres extension.  It returns one row for each combination in the `distinct on` clause -- in this case, one per `crop_type`.

The row returned is the first one encountered, base don the `order by` clause.  The first columns in the `order by` should match the columns in the `distinct on`.  The remaining columns then define "first".

Comment: with this I get only the very first entry of the specific crop, however they can be cultivated later on again, so they are not distinct

Comment: @JuliusDiel . . . Your question is quite specifically "I want to get the first entry (datum, crop_type) where a specific crop is cultivated", which this answers.  If you have a *different* question, then ask it as a *new* question, with a clear explanation of what you want to do, sample data, and desired results.  If you edit this question, you may invalidate this answer which can attract downvotes.